# How to re-connect to USB device without user gesture?

Tags: usb, webusb

I am writing a web page that will perform software upgrade on custom USB device. Firstly a user performs user gesture to connect to the device and starts procedure. Then page is still open but the device resets itself. Is there a way to connect again to this device (which is already paired) without user gesture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the device keeps the same vendor ID, product ID and serial number then the previously granted permission will still apply when the device resets. You can register a listener on `navigator.usb` for the `connect` event to be notified when the device reconnects. If those 3 identifiers change when the device resets then the browser can't tell the device is the same as the one the user granted the site permission to access previously.

Comment: Thanks for response. It turned out that my device reported empty serial number.