# Can webusb automatically connect without user-gesture, when device has no serial number?

Tags: usb, webusb

I am writing a web-app, where my users use, a DS2490 ibutton reader, zebra scanner, zebra printer and Loadstar di1000 Loadcell. I run chrome os flex on the devices, that run this webapp, and i manage them via the google admin console. I am using the following policies: WebUsbAllowDevicesForUrls, UsbDetachableAllowlist, to give the web-app access to the usb devices

All devices, but the ibutton reader connect automatically, when the page is loaded.

I found this post, where the asker had kind of the same problem as me. It looks like the problem was that his custom usb device didn't have a serial number, and he solved it by giving it a one. When i look at the usb data of the ibutton reader, it shows that the serial number string is empty. Can the lack of a serial number have anything to do with the device not automatically connecting?

the post:
[How to re-connect to USB device without user gesture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376562/how-to-re-connect-to-usb-device-without-user-gesture/56387128#56387128)

Connect function:

```
  async connect(e) {
    try {
      this.device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice(this.requestParams);
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      let devices = await navigator.usb.getDevices();
      devices.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.vendorId == this.deviceFilter.vendorId && element.productId == this.deviceFilter.productId) {
          this.device = element
        }
      });
    }
    if (this.device) {
      this.eventTarget.dispatchEvent(new Event('connect'));
      await this.device.open();
      await this.device.selectConfiguration(1);
      await this.device.claimInterface(0);
      this.connected = true
      this.eventTarget.dispatchEvent(new Event('open'));
      this.search = true
      this.searchLoop()
    } else {
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems like a bug or user error. Make sure you have the vendor and product IDs set correctly for all the devices you want to get permission for by policy. The policy-based permission logic does not require the device to have a serial number.

If you are using Web Serial or WebHID for some of these devices note that they use different policies, `SerialAllowUsbDevicesForUrls` and `WebHidAllowDevicesForUrls`. Please reach out to your Enterprise support representative if you can't find these policies in the Admin Console.

**Note**: You probably don't need to set the `UsbDetachableAllowlist` policy unless one of those devices have a driver that automatically attaches when the device is connected.

Comment: I have checked that the VID and PID is correctly set in the settings. I just tried to clear all website data and cookies on one of the kiosk machines. Now none of the devices connect. So i think you are right, that it is a user error. I think the permissions for the other devices were stored. Is there a special way you need to connect when you want to use permission by policy? I have added my connect function in the question

Comment: Rather than calling `requestDevice()` and then falling back to `getDevices()` on failure you will want to call `getDevices()` first to see what devices the site already has permission to access. The policy has no effect on the behavior of the `requestDevice()` method.